# ggplot2: how to horizontal center legend at top of plot with long Y-axis labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to plot some data with really long Y-axis labels. I want to position the legend at the top of the plot, and center it horizontally w.r.t. the entire plot width (as dictated by the width of the panel + the Y-axis labels). I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Here is the toy data I have been working with:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

iris_new <- iris

iris_new %<>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Width = paste0(Sepal.Width, 
                              paste0(sample(letters, size = 100, replace = TRUE), 
                                     collapse = "")))

plt0 <- ggplot(iris_new, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point() + theme(legend.position = "top", legend.direction = "horizontal")

plt0
```

The basic plot:
[image: plt0]

`legend.justification = "left"` simulates what I want, but not perfectly since it is simply aligning the legend to the left margin of the panel, and it just so happens that this approximately coincides with the middle of the plot width.

```
plt1 <- plt0 + theme(legend.justification = "left")
plt1
```

[image: plt1]

But this solution isn't really satisfactory as I cannot guarantee that the Y-axis labels might not get longer (or shorter). Of course, I could use `stringr::str_wrap()` to limit the label width to say 40 characters, but I really want to know if there is a simple `ggplot2` solution to the alignment issue. This would also not account for the fact that the plotted data might force the X-axis to vary between plots.

`guides(fill = guide_legend(title.position = "left", label.position = "left"))` and `guides(fill = guide_legend(title.hjust = 0, label.hjust = 0))` didn't work either.

The expected output would be something like this (simulated using `LibreOffice Impress`):
[image: plt2]

I apologize if this is a trivial question. I did try and search for relevant posts on `stackoverflow`, but I was unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is close to what you require

```
p1 <-ggplot(iris_new, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point()

p2 <- p1 + theme(legend.position = "top")
le1 <- cowplot::get_legend(p1)
le1


cowplot::plot_grid(p2, le1, nrow = 2, rel_heights = c(1, 0.2))
```

Although I do see another legend at the bottom not sure how to remove it but horizontal center its close

[image: fig]

Comment: Um, that isn't anywhere close to what I'm hoping to do, unless I'm misunderstanding something here. In the plot depicted in your answer, for instance, my expected solution would have been to have the legend on the top placed exactly halfway along the width of the plot. I do appreciate your effort though.